# SharePoint workflow - selecting items

Tags: workflow, email

I am very inexperienced with SharePoint, but I was tasked with following project. Have our Company store moved online to sharepoint. The idea is to have an excel spreadsheet with all of our items on sharepoint site. It would have 3 set culumns: Part number, Name of item, price, and one interactive column with checkmark, if they want the item, and another with quantity.

When they would select the items, by checkmarking them, and selecting the quantity, they would hit submit/workflow and an email with the selected items would be delivered to a specific warehouse org email. Then the warehouse personel could prepare the item and our delivery personel would deliver the item to the individual.

How can I make this reality? Can anyone help please?

For now I have very basic sharepoint store... I just copy/pasted line by line into the Inserted table, and have customers copy and paste the line and send it to the warehouse using their email.

[image]

I would like to automate this as much as possible without the users having to start a new email, copy and paste the lines, and then sending it to the warehouse.

Thank you very much

Comment: First of all, this is a _very_ broad question and would consist of several steps. Having that said - SharePoint's OOTB features don't really suite for a web store. At best I'd imagine that there would be drawbacks here and there which wouldn't be a problem with e.g. a basic WordPress web store plugin. I'd advice you to look for SharePoint plugins which could make this requirement possible. I don't have anything to recommend though.

Comment: Several questions... Do you have JavaScript skills, or access to a JavaScript developer? Also which SharePoint are you using? 2007,2010,2013,2016,2019, SharePoint Online? Are InfoPath and SharePoint Designer supported/permitted in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I see a very simple solution. 1 workflow is more than enough

**Form Customization:**

In the newform.aspx page just add a content editor web part and you can customize/manipulate the existing fields.

**Workflow:**

After creating an item  in the SharePoint list - Start a workflow

Your workflow should send a mail. In that mail try to provision all the item details created and send it to the warehouse org.

If the warehouse person have access to your site, then add one more column as " progress "

Once the mail is triggered change the status "In progress " and after item preparation is done you can allow warehouse person to update the field value status to " Delivered ".

If you need more help let me know.

Thanks...

Comment: Hello,thank you for your message, unfortunatelly I am unable to downlaod the Sharepoint designer as my organization is blocking downloads. We are a government organization, thus we re 30 years behind... :( I have to work with waht I have... that is why I am asking for the help with the email, as that is the only solution for me .